# Accessing ActiveDirectory properties belong to objectClass=posixGroup

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap, active-directory-group

I am trying to update the `memberUid` property of the `posixGroup`.

1. I do a directory search and find my record.  If I loop through the `searchresults.property` I can list the values (it is defined as Multi-value) of the field.
2. I define a `DirectoryEntry` using the `searchresults.getdirectory` method.

If I do anything with the property from this `directoryentry`, for instance check if it exists (`property.contain`), or list it or try to update it I get an unknown error `x'8000500C'`.

The fields `cn` and `description`' do not cause this problem.

If I add other user defined properties I also get the error.

How can I work with properties belonging to this type of schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error looks like it is:
8000500c The Active Directory datatype cannot be converted to/from a native DS datatype

This seems to imply that the data returned is not a native AD datatype.

There seems to be a workaround at this [article.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c800f3e0-a1a3-4f9c-9045-9e3a7e3d2e98/directoryservices-ldap-80005000-or-8000500c-errors)